# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing' - in my virtual env in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I have created a virtual env in my vscode with the command:

```
conda create -p mlenv python==3.12 -y
```

activate my conda environment, then created a setup.py file and added 2 lines as below:

```
from setuptools import find_packages,setup
from typing import List
```

as soon a try to run it I'm getting the below error:

```
(/Volumes/Rooby/Training/end_to_end_ML/mlenv) Rooby@ Rooby-MacBook-Pro-2 end_to_end_ML % pip install --upgrade pip
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Rooby/Training/end_to_end_ML/mlenv/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/Volumes/Rooby/Training/end_to_end_ML/mlenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing'
```

I tried the commands as per someones suggestion: pip install --upgrade pip - still getting the same error:

please suggest.

After checking pip --version.
getting the same error:

```
(base) Robby@Robby-MacBook-Pro-2 end_to_end_ML % conda env list
# conda environments:
#
     base                  *  /Users/Robby/anaconda3
                             /Volumes/Robby/Training/end_to_end_ML/mlenv

(base) Robby@Robby-MacBook-Pro-2 end_to_end_ML % conda activate /Volumes/Robby/Training/end_to_end_ML/mlenv

(/Volumes/Robby/Training/end_to_end_ML/mlenv) Robby@Robby-MacBook-Pro-2 end_to_end_ML % pip --version
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Robby/Training/end_to_end_ML/mlenv/bin/pip",      line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File         "/Volumes/Robby/Training/end_to_end_ML/mlenv/lib/python3.12/site-     packages/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import List, Optional
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing'
(/Volumes/Robby/Training/end_to_end_ML/mlenv) Robby@Robby-     MacBook-Pro-2 end_to_end_ML %
```

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip --version`

Comment: its very strange, if I type anything in the terminal of my vscode, I get the above error message - saying No module names 'typing' - its so annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used a pip upgrade command in your conda environment. Try installing/upgrading the the module you want using a conda install command in your environment, and if still does not work, try installing/upgrading it through conda forge channel.

Hope it helps.

Comment: do you suggest any commands that I can try

Answer (score 0):

You may need to point your vs code to the right interpreter to get it to pick up the packages.

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+P: select Interpreter

Answer (score 0):

This was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter.

You could use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python:Select Interpreter" to choose the python interpreter which you installed the package in.

You can also use command `pip install packageName` in the terminal to install the package in your current python interpreter.

[Read document about python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters) for more details.